# References on particle cooling

Tags: particle-physics, resource-recommendations, laser, oscillators, cooling

I am looking for references on the topic of particle and mechanical oscillators cooling, in particular:

- Doppler cooling
- Resolved sideband cooling and Lamb-Dicke regime
- Stokes and anti-stokes modes and side-bands
- Franck–Condon principle and applications
- Any other related stuff

I feel that in general the nomenclature in the papers is a bit confusing (e.g. talking about 
"phonons" when -I think- they really refer to normal modes), so a comprehensive and reliable reference would be much appreciated.